# Returning an array with Angular 2 provider

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a provider to simply return an array. I'm fairly new to Angular and am not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I'm getting the following error:

'[ts] A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.'

Can anyone see what the issue?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class StatesProvider {

  states:{};

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello StatesProvider Provider');
  }

  getStates(){

    this.states = {[

      {
          "name": "Alabama",
          "abbreviation": "AL"
      },
      {
          "name": "Alaska",
          "abbreviation": "AK"
      },
      {
          "name": "American Samoa",
          "abbreviation": "AS"
      },
      {
          "name": "Arizona",
          "abbreviation": "AZ"
      },
      {
          "name": "Arkansas",
          "abbreviation": "AR"
      },
      {
          "name": "California",
          "abbreviation": "CA"
      }

     ... (etc)

  ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare the states as any or array of objects,

```
states:any;
```

and return the array inside the **`getStates`**

```
 getStates() : any {

    this.states = {[
      {
          "name": "Alabama",
          "abbreviation": "AL"
      },
      {
          "name": "Alaska",
          "abbreviation": "AK"
      }
    ];    
   return this.states;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your code (which I repeat below) is creating an object, whose (first) property name could not be determined by Typescript:

```
this.states = {[
  {
      "name": "Alabama",
      "abbreviation": "AL"
  },
  ...
]}
```

Typescript thinks you are defining an object (by the `{}`), with a property whose name Typescript expects to be either a string, a number, a symbol or any identifying name. But you instead have `[{"name": "Alabama", "abbreviation": "AL"}, ... ]`.

It would work if you instead have `this.states = { arrayOfStates: [{"name": "Alabama", "abbreviation": "AL"}, ... ] }`. In this case, you are defining `this.states` as an object with a array property named `arrayOfStates`.

But based on your question, you seem to simply want to return an array, rather than an object with an array property.

So you should define `states` as an array instead of defining it as an object. To define is as an array that contains `any` type:

```
states: any[];
```

And then assign an array to it in `getStates`:

```
getStates() : any[] {
    this.states = [
      {
          "name": "Alabama",
          "abbreviation": "AL"
      },
      ...  // Some elements removed for brevity
    ];

    return this.states;
}
```

Note there are no curly brackets enclosing the square brackets.