# Function was working, but now says it is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service that returns an array of states. It was working (thanks Sajeetharan), but now I'm getting a page error saying that it's not a function.

```
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    private contactService: ContactsProvider,
    private stateService: StatesProvider,
    private auth: AuthenticationProvider) {

    this.contactId = this.navParams.get('contactId');

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.contactService.getContactById(this.contactId)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.contact = res.json();
        this.contactInitials = this.contact.first_name.charAt(0) + this.contact.last_name.charAt(0);
      })

    this.states = this.stateService.getStates();

  }
```

The specific error is

> : Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.stateService.getStates
>   is not a function

.

What could cause this?

Comment: post your service

Comment: is your `getStates` function public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this quesiton is a continuation of your previous **[`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786730/returning-an-array-with-angular-2-provider/49786739#49786739)**

in order to access your service method you need to set the access specifier as **`public`**.

```
public getStates(){

}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks Sajeetharan! You're really helped me out. Cheers!